# Open Source Quadratic Programming with Piecewise Linear Objective

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, open-source

I am looking for an open source solver to solve the a quadratic programming problem with an additional piecewise linear objective, as show below. The problem is fairly small ($\mathbf{x}$ is a vector of dimension 120).

\begin{equation*}
 \max_{x}: \mathbf{x}^{T} \mathbf{q_0}
 - \mathbf{x^{T}} P_0 \mathbf{x} - f(\mathbf{x})
\end{equation*}

Note that above $P_0$ is positive semidefinite and $f$ is piecewise linear for each variable in $\mathbf{x}$ but not convex. For each $x_i$, $i \in \left\{1, ..., 120\right\}$, $f(x)$ would be a vector of coordinate points, e.g.

```
[(x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1), ..., (x_N, y_N)]
```

For any given $x_i$, $f(x_i)$ looks something like the following.

[image]

Since $f$ does not depend on any cross terms in $\mathbf{x}$, the above optimization could also be written as

\begin{equation*}
 \max_{x}: \mathbf{x}^{T} \mathbf{q_0}
 - \mathbf{x^{T}} P_0 \mathbf{x} - (f(x_1) + ... + f(x_{120}))
\end{equation*}

The are also linear constraints of the form $A\mathbf{x} < \mathbf{b}$ are added.

I have formulated the problem in Gurobi which is fairly straightforward but was hoping to compare this to an open source solver. Looking around it seems like GLPK would work for this, but I have no experience using this library so was hoping for a bit of info related to this or alternative solutions.

A sample problem for gurobi using the matlab API is shown below.

```
N = 2;

q_0 = [-3.31e3, -5.07e3];
P_0 = [-0.90e-04  -0.63e-04;
       -0.63e-04  -0.90e-04];

x = [-2.0000e9, -1.0000e9, -0.8000e9, -0.6000e9, -0.4000e9, -0.2500e9,...
    -0.1000e9, -0.0500e9, -0.0250e9, -0.0100e9, -0.0010e9, 0, 0.0010e9,...
    0.0100e9, 0.0250e9, 0.0500e9, 0.1000e9, 0.2500e9, 0.4000e9,...
    0.6000e9, 0.8000e9, 1.0000e9, 2.0000e9];

y = [2.938964e6, 0.753364e6, 0.488104e6, 0.280144e6, 0.129472e6,...
    0.053766e6, 0.011007e6, 0.003751e6, 0.001435e6, 0.000465e6,...
    0.000037e6, 0, 0.000037e6, 0.000465e6, 0.001435e6, 0.003751e6,...
    0.011007e6, 0.053766e6, 0.129472e6, 0.280144e6, 0.488104e6,...
    0.753364e6, 2.938964e6];

params.outputflag = 0;

%formulate model
model.obj = zeros(N, 1);
model.Q = sparse(P_0);
model.A = sparse(zeros(1, N));
model.sense = '=';
model.rhs = 0;
model.ub = repmat(1e9, N, 1);
model.lb = repmat(-1e9, N, 1);
model.modelsense = 'max';

% piecewise tcosts
for i = 1:2
    model.pwlobj(i).var = i;
    model.pwlobj(i).x   = x;
    model.pwlobj(i).y   = x * q_0(i) - y;
end

result = gurobi(model, params);
```

Comment: In what form are you give $f(x)$?  Are there additional constraints?

Comment: @BrianBorchers responded inline to comment

Comment: Are the $y_{i}$ precise values or are they noisy?

Comment: I am slightly confused by how to interpret noisy here. The function $f$ is an approximation to reality, and in that sense is noisy. However from the perspective of this problem $f$ is a piecewise linear function, not a function which I am approximating using a piecewise linear function, and in that sense the $y_i$s are exact.

Comment: If the $y_{i}$ are measured values with measurement errors, then you most likely want to smooth the surface rather than using piecewise linear interpolation of the measured values.  You could for example use a smoothed spline interpolation.

Comment: I think my formulation previously was a bit unclear. The piecewise linear function operates on each variable individually, I have attempted to clarify above.

Comment: When you formulated this in Gurobi, how did you handle the piecewise linear $f(x)$?  Did you use binary variables to specify which interval you were in?

Comment: For the piecewise linear component I used the field `pwlobj`, https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.5/refman/matlab_gurobi.html

Comment: Gurobi is apparently formulating this as an MIQP, which glpk's solver won't be able to handle.  There are some other open source solvers for mixed integer nonlinear programming that you might apply to your problem.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks a lot for the info. Any suggestion on solvers to check out for this?

Comment: See the list of codes at: https://www.math.hu-berlin.de/~stefan/minlpsoft.pdf

Comment: @BrianBorchers, old thread but I was revisiting this and was wondering where you found that Gurobi formulates these as MIQP in their documentation? I can't seem to find any reference to this

Comment: In case anyone stumbles across this, there is a video detailing it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjPXLRfBtL8, relevant portion is at 46:15